# Seeding with Random library Java yielding same results

Tags: java, random

My method for generating a Random Integer is done like so:

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

I am using this to choose random routes for the travelling salesman problem.

But for some odd reason it keeps finding the same route after ~5 seconds.

There is a small bit of variation but almost identical. Any idea why this is the case?

My guess is that in milliseconds just isn't precise enough. Should I go down to nanoseconds?

Comment: **Use the same `Random` instance**. Do not create a `new` one each time.

Comment: Instantiate the `Random` outside of the method.

Comment: Shouldn't I keep seeding regularly?

Comment: We're not going to go into the technicalities of [linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Keep a `Random` instance and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending an the frequence you call your method per second, you initialize the `Random` with the same seed. As already mentioned instantiate the `Random` outside of your method.

a small snippet to demonstrate the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("random with same seed");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt(100));
    }

    System.out.println("random initialized once");
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

output (yours will have different values)

```
random with same seed
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
random initialized once
13
96
11
34
44
22
80
10
41
36
```

If you create a `Random` with the same seed, it will generate the same "random" values and in the same consecutive order. If you initialize the `Random` only once and with a more ore less random seed, it will produce each run different consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

With reseeding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(randInt(1, 100));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(randInt(1, 100));
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Results:

[image]

Seeding once as a class variable:

```
private static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(randInt(1, 100));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(randInt(1, 100));
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Results:

[image]